# WebStorm started to highlight red all of SCSS files

Tags: sass, webstorm

I have a problem with my WebStorm 2016.

I don't know why but all of sudden it started to highlight red all of my `.scss` files. Files are 100% semantically correct. All semicolons in them are highlighted with note "end of line expected" or "unexpected term".

I don't know how this happened and how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE

Comment: if invalidating caches doesn't help, please attach a screenshot that shows up the issue. Make sure that this screenshot includes the icon in file tab, so that it's clear what file type the file is associated with

Comment: Problem solved, thanks for help :)